# ErrorException Array to string conversion after command php artisan make:middleware Cors [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

I try to run command `php artisan make:middleware Cors`

But I got this error after that

```
   ErrorException 

  Array to string conversion

    372▕         $config = $this->laravel['config'];
    373▕
    374▕         $provider = $config->get('auth.guards.'.$config->get('auth.defaults.guard').'.provider');
    375▕
  ➜ 376▕         return $config->get("auth.providers.{$provider}.model");        

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError()

  2   Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand::userProviderModel()
```

My providers array from config/auth.php is

```
'providers' => [
                'users' => [
                    'driver' => 'eloquent',
                    'model' => App\Models\User::class,
                ],
            ],
```

My guards array from config/auth.php is

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => [
                'users' => [
                    'driver' => 'eloquent',
                    'model' => App\Models\User::class,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

What is the solution?

Comment: what is set in `config/auth.php` for `defaults.guard`? once you know that, check `guards.thatDefaultGuard.provider`

Comment: `defaults.guard` is `web` @lagbox and my `guards.web.provider` is `users.driver.eloquent` and `users.model.App\Models\User::class`

Comment: add the `'providers'` array from `config/auth.php` to your question

Comment: @ratavagn are you doing the multi auth using passport ?

Comment: yes I am using passport @Muhammad

Comment: how about the `'guards'` array

Comment: ok added @lagbox

Comment: in guards array for web remove the users model and just paste this 'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ]

Comment: @Muhammad solved! thank you Sir!